# Google shopping api Request had insufficient authentication scopes

Tags: authentication, curl, google-api, permission-denied, google-shopping-api

I make a request to Google shopping by curl:

```
curl --request POST \
  'https://shoppingcontent.googleapis.com/content/v2.1/products/batch?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"entries":[]}' \
  --compressed
```

and the response is

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Insufficient Permission",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "insufficientPermissions"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

I'm sure my access_token is right, but I'm not sure if my API_KEY is right.
My API_KEY is gotten in https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials , and the API_KEY's restrictions is none.
[image]

And my Content API for Shopping is enabled:
[image]

I wonder if I miss any critical method, that I can't request the api successfully.

By the way, how can I get my merchant_id? Is it my merchant_id?
[image]

But the method "Verify and claim your website URL in Business information", I didn't pass. Does it cause to the 403 error?

Comment: YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN <-- where did you get the access token and what scopes did you use when creating it?

Comment: I get the access token by this way: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/oauth/overview.

Comment: curl \
  -d code=[get my code by this way https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/oauth/overview] \
  -d client_id=[ get my client id by https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials] \
  -d client_secret=[get my code by this wayhttps://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/oauth/overview ] \
  -d redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob \
  -d grant_type=authorization_code https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token